# Dynamically Create Div on Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, loops

I am trying to dynamically create several divs upon an AJAX request. I am able to create them, but something is wrong with my for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.stylist_1.length; i++) {

    stylist1Addresses.push(data.stylist_1[i]);

    for (x = 0; x < stylist1Addresses.length; x++) {
        var temp = document.createElement("div");
        temp.className = "unit";
        temp.innerHTML = stylist1Addresses[i].Address;
        document.getElementById("list").appendChild(temp);
    }
}
```

As you can see in this JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/joptmqh8/), it creates 6 divs. Why? It should only create divs with the first 3 addresses in `stylist_1` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the inner loop:

```js
var data = {
    "stylist_1": [{
        "Address": "1 Stn Main",
            "Phone": "403-990-9033"
    }, {
        "Address": "474 Cirrus Rd",
            "Phone": "403-995-3243"
    }, {
        "Address": "1591 Stn St",
            "Phone": "403-982-8893"
    }],
        "stylist_2": [{
        "Address": "219 Welch Blvd",
            "Phone": "587-436-3171"
    }, {
        "Address": "374 Main Rd",
            "Phone": "587-315-9431"
    }, {
        "Address": "564 Main Rd",
            "Phone": "403-938-9983"
    }]
}

var stylist1Addresses = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.stylist_1.length; i++) {
    stylist1Addresses.push(data.stylist_1[i]);

    var temp = document.createElement("div");
    temp.className = "unit";
    temp.innerHTML = stylist1Addresses[i].Address;
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(temp);
}
console.log(stylist1Addresses);
```

```css
.unit:nth-child(odd) {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

```html
<div id="list"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I chose this because it requires one less for loop to write.

Answer (score 3):

your for loops should be seperate:

```
var stylist1Addresses = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.stylist_1.length; i++) {
    stylist1Addresses.push(data.stylist_1[i]);
}
for (x = 0; x < stylist1Addresses.length; x++) {
        var temp = document.createElement("div");
        temp.className = "unit";
        temp.innerHTML = stylist1Addresses[x].Address;
        document.getElementById("list").appendChild(temp);
    }
console.log(stylist1Addresses);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because your inner loop is executing for every iteration of the outer loop.

And you see 1, 2 & then 3 instances of the appendedElement because in the inner loop, the element to append is specified by `i` (`temp.innerHTML = stylist1Addresses[i].Address;`) which is appended `x` times.

Corrected Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/joptmqh8/2/

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

updated your jsfiddle `here`
http://jsfiddle.net/1qdn55v3/. 
once you pushed all the address in *stylist1Addresses*  close the for loop and create one more for loop for creating divs